# How to sort with 0 on the end in result

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a list of products with prices. Some products are prices only aviable on request. This products are labeled with a price of 0 in the database.
If I now make a request like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ORDER BY Price ASC";
```

The Results are of course starts with a price of 0.
But I want all the 0 prices at the end of the results.
Is this possible with a SQL request or what is the best solution to re-sort in php?
Thx in advanced
Bernd

Comment: ORDER BY price = 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may sort using a `CASE` expression which places zero prices last:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE ...
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Price > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    Price;
```

In MySQL, the `ORDER BY` clause can be simplified:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE ...
ORDER BY
    Price = 0,    -- false (0) for positive prices, true (1) for zero prices
    Price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using bitwise negation to make 0 the maximum value for a bigint in the sort.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Price = 0 THEN ~0 ELSE Price END ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can mysql FIELD function to retrieve the data in the order you want

```
   SELECT * FROM products WHERE ORDER BY FIELD(Price,0) ASC
```